# softether VPN access list not working

Tags: networking, server, permissions, vpn

I installed softether as VPN server on UBUNTU 12.4. nOW I add anonymous user for special range of ips. 
as you see blow i created a user named 'all' : 
[image]

and i created an access list to deny access from range of IPs:

[image]

Now access list not working and users can connect from all IPs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are creating a traffic ACL on the virtual hub at:

- Manage Virtual Hub -> Manage Access Lists

This kind of rule does not restrict connections to the virtual hub.

If you want to restrict connections to the virtual hub from a particular subnet, then you need to set a rule at:

- Manage Virtual Hub -> Virtual Hub Properties -> IP Address Control
  List

The default rule permits access. To get the desired result, create two new rules like this:

- Permit, Multiple IP Addresses, Address = 2.144.0.0, Net Mask =
  255.252.0.0, Priority = 100
- Deny, Multiple IP Addresses, Address = 0.0.0.0, Net Mask = 0.0.0.0, Priority = 200